# Is there an R function for merge several asc files?

Tags: r

I tried to merge several asc files of long term data of snow cover in r

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
f<-list.files(pattern=".asc", full.names = TRUE)
r<-lapply(f, raster)

a <- do.call("merge",r) 

a <- do.call("merge",r)
```

But this script gives

> "Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
>     different origin"

All rasters have the same length. How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is at https://www.r-bloggers.com/merge-asc-grids-with-r/
where you have to set the tolerance using loop like this:

```
for(i in 2:length(r)){  
 x<-merge(x=r[[1]],y=r[[i]],tolerance=5000,overlap=T)  
 r[[1]]<-x  
 }
```